# Swift: How to execute an async function only after previous async function completes

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency

I have a function which in turn executes four functions. The tricky part seems to be getting them to execute in the right order. After function1 is complete I would like to execute function2 and function3, which can run simultaneously. When function2 and function3 are both complete, I would like to run function4.

Consider:

```
func initializeMe() {
    Task {
        await loadMyData()
        await loadMyLikes()
        await loadMyAdmirers()
        loadMyFriends()
    }
}
```

The process should be:

- `loadMyData()` loads the user's data from a Firestore database, which includes an array called likes which is full of user ids.
- `loadMyLikes()` loads users from Firestore, based on the likes array loaded in `loadMyData()`
- `loadMyAdmirers()` also loads users, this time looking for the current user's id in other users likes
- `loadMyFriends()` looks for user ids common to both `myLikes` and `myAdmirers`.

Concurrency is tough for me, and I get the sense I may need completion handlers here too. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with your existing code? That looks like the exact thing you are trying to do. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Don’t mix completion handlers and async await. If you aren’t using a pure async await approach you will have the issues you describe. Firestore has pure async await versions of all their functions, don’t use the old ones.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `loadMyLikes` and `loadMyAdmirers` to run concurrently, there are two common patterns.

1. A “task group”, using [`withTaskGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withtaskgroup(of:returning:body:)/):

   ```swift
   func initializeMe() async {
       await loadMyData()
       await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { [self] group in
           group.addTask { await loadMyLikes() }
           group.addTask { await loadMyAdmirers() }
       }
       loadMyFriends()
   }
   ```
2. Use [`async let`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0317-async-let.md):

   ```swift
   func initializeMe() async {
       await loadMyData()
       async let likes = loadMyLikes()
       async let admirers = loadMyAdmirers()
       await likes
       await admirers
       loadMyFriends()
   }
   ```

Both of these will:

- `await loadMyData()`;
- when that finishes, run `loadMyLikes` and `loadMyAdmirers` concurrently; and
- when those two are done, run `loadMyFriends`.

---

Two final observations:

- Personally, I would be wary of burying unstructured concurrency (the `Task {…}`) inside this function. The caller has no way of knowing when it’s done. You also forfeit the possibility of cancelation.

  In the above, I made this an `async` function, and if I really needed to bridge from an non-`async` context, I personally would do that where `initializeMe` was called, not here. Feel free to do whatever you want, but be very sensitive to the implications of hiding unstructured concurrency (or at least doing that without doing the prerequisite overhead of saving the `Task`, writing some cancelation handler code, figuring out how you will update the UI with the results, etc.).

  There is simply not enough here to advise you further on this topic (and it is beyond the scope of this question), but, in short, be careful with [unstructured concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency#Unstructured-Concurrency).
- You are apparently storing the results of these functions in properties. Sometimes we want to do that (so that we can observe data changes as updated information comes in), but often we will not.

  E.g., when `loadMyData` finishes, but we haven’t finished the other three methods, what is to be shown in the UI? The data without likes/admirers/friends? Or nothing until everything is done?

  Bottom line, the alternative approach is to write these functions in such a manner that they do *not* update properties, but rather `return` their respective results. We might hold this in local variables and only update the properties with our locally stored results when all four methods are done.

  It is completely up to you, but I wanted to bring this alternative approach to your attention at the very least.